# How to install glib 1.2 on new system?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, c, glib

I try to install glib 1.2 on Ubiuntu 21.04 to run [old c program](https://github.com/adammaj1/Some-Julia-sets-by-Michael-Becker-)

After succesfull

```
./configure --build=i386-linux-gnu --host=i386-linux-gnu
```

I try

```
make
```

with error :

```bsh
 make check
Making check in .
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu '/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0'
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall  -D_REENTRANT  -o libglib.la -rpath /usr/local/lib -version-info 0:0:0  -release 1.2 garray.lo gcache.lo gcompletion.lo gdataset.lo gdate.lo gerror.lo ghash.lo ghook.lo giochannel.lo giounix.lo glist.lo gmain.lo gmem.lo gmessages.lo gmutex.lo gnode.lo gprimes.lo grel.lo gscanner.lo gslist.lo gstrfuncs.lo gstring.lo gtimer.lo gtree.lo gutils.lo  
rm -fr .libs/libglib.la .libs/libglib.* .libs/libglib-1.2.*

*** Warning: This library needs some functionality provided by -lc.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname -Wl,libglib-1.2.so.0 -o .libs/libglib-1.2.so.0.0.0 garray.lo gcache.lo gcompletion.lo gdataset.lo gdate.lo gerror.lo ghash.lo ghook.lo giochannel.lo giounix.lo glist.lo gmain.lo gmem.lo gmessages.lo gmutex.lo gnode.lo gprimes.lo grel.lo gscanner.lo gslist.lo gstrfuncs.lo gstring.lo gtimer.lo gtree.lo gutils.lo
/usr/bin/ld: gcache.lo: in function `g_bit_nth_lsf':
...

/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0/glib.h:1560: multiple definition of `g_bit_nth_msf'; garray.lo:/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0/glib.h:1560: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: gutils.lo: in function `g_bit_storage':
/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0/glib.h:1578: multiple definition of `g_bit_storage'; garray.lo:/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0/glib.h:1578: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:296: libglib.la] Błąd 1
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu '/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0'
make: *** [Makefile:403: check-recursive] Błąd 1
```

I have googled the error info without result. Is the solution for this ?

========edit===

After glib installation using method by Knud

```
 make
cc -ansi -Wall -g -I /usr/include/glib-1.2 -I /usr/include/gtk-1.2 -I /usr/lib/glib/include  -c julia2.c
julia2.c:8:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
    8 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:16: julia2.o] Błąd 1
```

so no errors from compilation. Additional check :

```
find . -name '*.so.*' -type f -exec file {} \;
./snap/brave/121/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/WidevineCdm/4.10.2209.0/_platform_specific/linux_x64/libwidevinecdm.so.sig: data
./snap/brave/120/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/WidevineCdm/4.10.2209.0/_platform_specific/linux_x64/libwidevinecdm.so.sig: data
./Pobrane/hplip-3.21.6/.libs/libhpmud.so.0.0.6: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=02c7f5f977604305c3a6d6167f8f87455922a882, not stripped
./Pobrane/hplip-3.21.6/.libs/libhpipp.so.0.0.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=46158ce64a378404dc4008aaed0b65f67c4bd4a4, not stripped
./Pobrane/hplip-3.21.6/.libs/libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=5277f7887124074022671d51263eae68e234588c, not stripped
./Pobrane/hplip-3.21.6/.libs/libhpdiscovery.so.0.0.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=3c4d2def464c65586af097c4e06f3c4b13d8b203, not stripped
./Pobrane/hplip-3.21.6/.libs/libhpip.so.0.0.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=297d1bea4175bb34ba1b989a4219c12b7c615fe1, not stripped
```

but ldconfig shows libglib 1.2, 2.0 and 2.4 between 1249 shared libraries

```
ldconfig -p>s.txt

...
libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
    libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
    libglib-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    libglib-1.2.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/libglib-1.2.so.0
```

Comment: glib 1.2 is ancient, last updated in 1999.  You'd be better off updating the code to work with glib 2.0....and even 2.0 has been around since 2002 (but it has been regularly updated, once or twice a year ever since).   conversion could be anything from "trivial, only needed to change a few function calls" to "rewrite, the library has changed beyond recognition".  even at the exteme end, though, it's likely to be less work (and less *wasted* work) than building glib 1.2 for a modern distro.

Comment: @cas I have also tried the same on the old ubuntu 11. The error was different : non numeric value.

Comment: AFAIK the stuff about `-lc` is just a warning - the actual error(s) that are causing the link phase to fail are the many `multiple definition of xxxxxx`, which appear to be a result of a change in the semantics of the C `inline` keyword. I suggest starting over and forcing the compiler to use a pre-C99 standard ex. `CFLAGS=-std=c89 ./configure --build=i386-linux-gnu --host=i386-linux-gnu` (you could also try `-std=ansi`). See [What does extern inline do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216546/4440445)

Comment: @steeldriver I have repeated cofigure, then add -std=ansi to the Makefile, but the result seems the same

Comment: ./configure --build=i386-linux-gnu --host=i386-linux-gnu CFLAGS="-std=ansi"

Comment: @Adam you would need at least to `make clean` **then** re-run the `./configure` and `make` commands - possibly `rm config.cache` to be certain. I tested it on Ubuntu 20.04, and it worked for me. Or start over by unpacking a clean copy of the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

? Build glib-1.2.10 : I don't think you can do that with a contemporary OS. The latest packages were built for Ubuntu 7.04? year 2007, probably with gcc-3.4.6 !

Please download from "old ubuntu" → libglib1.2_1.2.10-17build1_i386.deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib1.2/libglib1.2_1.2.10-17build1_i386.deb ... **and** libglib1.2-dev_1.2.10-17build1_i386.deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib1.2/libglib1.2-dev_1.2.10-17build1_i386.deb

The packages are installed OK, Ubuntu 21.04 - amd64

```
sudo apt install ./libglib1.2_1.2.10-17build1_i386.deb
sudo apt install ./libglib1.2-dev_1.2.10-17build1_i386.deb
```

... and `ldd` confirms `libglib-1.2.so.0.0.10` OK.

P.S.: The year 2005 gtk-1.2.10 packages should be usable too http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+1.2/

EDIT : `libgtk1.2-common:all` repacked to :i386 . Link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hRMXw6utPJdpNSZlxiXYIjOK4v3nmIQu?usp=sharing ... then no issues with Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/823286/libgtk1-2-deb-install-fails

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658860/how-to-install-gtk-1-2-on-new-system

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
*** Warning: This library needs some functionality provided by -lc.
```

(and similar about `-ldl` and `-lpthread`) do not appear to be fatal - what prevents the link phase from completing is the repeated `multiple definition` errors of the form

```
/usr/bin/ld: gutils.lo: in function `g_bit_storage':
/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0/glib.h:1578: multiple definition of `g_bit_storage'; garray.lo:/home/a/Pobrane/glib-1.2.0/glib.h:1578: first defined here
```

These appear to be the result of changes in the semantics of the C `inline` / `extern inline` constructs, as discussed in [What does extern inline do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216546/4440445) for example.

I was able to build the libraries on Ubuntu 20.04 by specifying a pre-C99 compiler standard as follows:

Either star over by unpacking a clean copy of the source tarball, or

```
make clean

rm config.cache
```

Then pass gcc option `-std=c89` via the `CFLAGS` environment variable:

```
CFLAGS=-std=c89 ./configure --build=i386-linux-gnu --host=i386-linux-gnu

make
```

resulting in the following shared libs:

```
$ find . -name '*.so.*' -type f -exec file {} \;
./.libs/libglib-1.2.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=b8a76e7ca4f2dfbb306557e3c8b287bdb3a6bd1f, not stripped
./gmodule/.libs/libgmodule-1.2.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=27a4d0fb60774b57ff0b0f9d6615ec6454ac144d, not stripped
./gmodule/.libs/libgplugin_a.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=7bb9dc8213fb6df1cfedac9dc7db4f3f4aeb26a0, not stripped
./gmodule/.libs/libgplugin_b.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=75c0683933afb87b39c2c81af14cb7d20b53e83b, not stripped
./gthread/.libs/libgthread-1.2.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=6812916591d4fa8fd1af74944bab7207b36774c5, not stripped
```

Note that we are building native 64-bit libraries here - the configure options `--build=i386-linux-gnu --host=i386-linux-gnu` only appear to be required because of the extremely aged `config.guess` and `config.sub` scripts in the source tarball - you can copy modern ones from your system's `/usr/share/automake-1.xx/` directory and then just use `CFLAGS=-std=c89 ./configure`